# Dummy-RDP connection popup after installation docker on Windows 11

Tags: remote-desktop, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, wsl2

I'm getting a dummy RDP popup with always the same GUID ().

In process explorer, I've figured out that the mstsc process is opened with the following parameters:

```
mstsc.exe /v:8CE980A0-176F-4254-830E-E1091E5374A4 /hvsocketserviceid:01EA7BD0-FACB-11E6-BD58-64006A7986D3 /silent /wslg /plugin:WSLDVC /wslgsharedmemorypath:WSL\8CE980A0-176F-4254-830E-E1091E5374A4\wslg C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\WSL\wslg.rdp
```

It will appear a few times and reappear after closing (Ok or Cancel).
I use the computer as dev tool (Rider, VS2022, VSCode, WSL2, etc)

Do you happen to know what is a purpose this popup? Can I disable it or "fix" it?

[dummy RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzaxb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I'm assuming that you are referring to Docker Desktop, right?  Since the window started coming up after installing Docker Desktop, can you try uninstalling temporarily to see if it goes away?  Not a solution, of course; just working on trying to identify the root cause.  Also, what Docker Desktop version?  And what does `wsl -l -v` show (from PowerShell)?  Finally, does `wsl --version` show any output (or just help text)?  If you can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1759021/edit) additional info into your question, that would be great - Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using rancher-desktop.
Output of `wsl -l -v`
  NAME                    STATE           VERSION
* rancher-desktop         Running         2
  rancher-desktop-data    Stopped         2